# Creating index on dynamically added fields in MongoDB

Tags: dynamic, indexing

I have a schema for MongoDB collection where fields are added dynamically to the document. The queries are tremendously slow when I perform a search for document with dynamically added fields.
The sample documents look like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4657439ad7f616df3f49"),
    "name" : "test1",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2014-06-13T10:48:41.501Z"),
    "Status" : "NEW",
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "rank":1278

}
```

Fields name, email, rank are dynamically created by user and added to the document. 
Querying with any of these fields taking very long to respond. No indexes are created on these field as the nature and fields themselves are added dynamically.
I have tried .explain(), here is the output:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1683063,
    "nscanned" : 1683063,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1683063,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1683063,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 4,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 1708,
    "indexBounds" : {

    }
```

This clearly shows that there is need to do indexing. But I have no clue how to create index on these non-deterministic fields. 
Note*:The document has no embedded documents as discussed [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13661/how-to-index-dynamic-attributes-in-mongodb). I am new to MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in 4.2 version MongoDb announced "Wildcard Indexes". It is what you are looking for. Here is an example how to create Wildcard index.

```
db.myCollection.createIndex( { "$**": 1 } );
```

Even you can create wildcard indexes for sub documents like that:

```
db.myCollection.createIndex( { "subdocument.$**": 1 } );
```

For more details: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-wildcard/

Answer (score 1):

You can create indexes on non deterministic fields. Just use [sparse indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/).

```
db.myCollection.ensureIndex( { "name": 1 }, { sparse: true } );
```

Comment: How can index to the filed 'name' added if it is not known until it is added dynamically?

Comment: well... if you're looking for automation, and users can add any field, you could ensure index before running the query for each field you're searching. After the first time, the ensureIndex command has no effect and it's harmless to repeat. This could, of course, lead to a collection with N indexes. It's a trade off.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Mongo DB, but if we talk about any database and table then its of no issue to create an Index on  non deterministic fields. its will be an extra burden on DB.. and your query may get slow during heavy retrival..